# Adjust numbers (iWork app) formula to add if 2 cells are 0, leave blank

Tags: numbers

I need help adding another rule to my formula, I need it to also say IF U17 and X17 both have 0 in them, then leave blank

Formula Y17
IF(OR(U17="",X17=""),"",IF(X17+V17=U17,"Push", IF(X17+V17>U17,W17,T17)))

If two cells have 0, then leave blank and also if two cells are blank to leave blank

Comment: Please do not cross post the same question on SE sites. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899961/adjust-formula-for-two-cells-that-are-0-in-iwork

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, the formula can be simplified to this:

`IFERROR(IF(OR(A2,B2),A2+B2,""),"")`

Since `0` resolves to `false` and `OR` takes Boolean values, just check for `0` in both cells and return the empty string.  (If both are `false` then the `true` event is not evaluated.)  Otherwise, if both are empty, the `IFERROR` will return the empty string as, for some reason, an empty string in Numbers is not treated as a Boolean `false` like in programming languages such as JavaScript.

See the example below.  This will work in Numbers on macOS or iOS.

[image: Table showing results of formula]

[image: Formula]